# Wordpress upload image and display in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

On a custom admin page (that is from a submenu of a plugin) I want to be able to upload an image and then display that image (or a thumnbnail of it) on a table like this:

(the table can be on another custom admin page or the same page, but I don't think it matters on what page the table will be)

```
Column 1 (image)   |    Column 2 (text)
----------------------------------------
[uploaded image]   | [text]
----------------------------------------
Column 1 (image)   |    Column 2 (text)
----------------------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm going to need more details. Do you mean upload a file in WordPress and show it? Or that a user on the website can upload a file, then show it; and if so is that file on the server or the client, is it stored in a server database or in localStorage? Finally what have you tried personally?

Comment: For what I am trying to achieve, only an admin can upload an image, and only from the custom admin page of the plugin. Also, the table is only visible to the admin. The table appears also on a custom admin page of the plugin. Later on I want to display these tables in posts, to the general public, but this is another subject. All the information displayed in the table should come from a DB, so maybe I can put the URL of the uploaded image there, I'm not sure. SO far I have made some attempts with wp_handle_upload() but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: For the DB have the file be uploaded to a repository on the server, and the file location as a string in the database. When you access the table you simply need to get the string location of the file and use it for the `src` of an `img` tag.

Comment: That sounds good but more than that, and what I don't know how to achieve is to have a button "Upload image" on the custom admin page that will help me upload that file. Basically when the admin presses this button, he should be able to pick an image from the computer or chose from an already uploaded one and then have the URL of the image saved in a database. After this I think I can display the image in the table simply by calling the URL from the DB. Maybe if I would see an example of it, it would enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a file, from which the user can chose what file they want to upload is easy to do since file uploading is a feature of HTML5. We can have an `<input>` element have type `file`:

```
<input type="file" name="imageFile"  />
```

And a form would for example, look something like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <!-- Note that 200000 is bytes -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <label>Files to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="imageFile"  />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>

</form>
```

**[Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bj7pLatf/1/).**

For the database we simple need to save the `POST["imageFile"]` as a string inside the database. I'm using PHP, Wordpress also uses PHP. For information on how to store uploaded files to a folder on your servers directory [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) is information from *php.net* on how to do that. Note that the information on files is within `$_FILES` in PHP.

To upload files to your directory on the sever you call [**move_uploaded_file()**.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very simple solution. I got a headache trying to use all kind of Wordpress functions.